# What reason and solution for WebConnector Error : "Update aborted. Company file is locked by another client ASP17"

Tags: quickbooks

I am using WebConnector version -2.1.0.30 with QuickBooks 2015 Enterprise.

WebConnector was working fine but all of a sudden when I run WebConnector and click on "Update Selected" button then it came up with this error (Note: by that time no one was logged on to QuickBooks).

Then as a quick fix I have deleted that QWC file and added a New one, that works fine.

Can any one please come up with a better solution and the reason behind this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you're running QuickBooks on a shared Windows Server, or in a hosted scenario with someone like Right Networks, Intuit Cloud, Cloud9, etc.

If so, this error means that Windows Server auto-logged-out some user and closed QuickBooks for them, but is still holding the file lock on the QuickBooks company file. Windows will automatically release the file lock after a short amount of time (usually 30 minutes to an hour).

There is no "fix" outside of waiting for a while, and then trying again.